# Qt виджеты в массив

Tags: qt, c++

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется несколько Qt виджетов типа `QSpinBox`, `QDoubleSpinBox`, `QSlider` и т.п.

Для них необходимо сделать некоторые одинаковые процедуры. Например:

```cpp
ui->mySpinBox1->setValue(1);
ui->mySpinBox2->setValue(2);
ui->mySlider->setValue(3);
...
```

Естественно когда элементов элементов много, а операции с ними однотипные, хочется все оформить циклом for. Для цикла for нужен список элементов. То есть конструкция типа

```
<Что-то> myWidgets = {ui->mySpinBox1, ui->mySpinBox2, ui->mySlider}
```

Тогда можно будет написать:

```
for (int a=0; a < количества_элементов; a++) {
    myWidgets[i]->setValue(valueList[i]);
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Comment: Я только делал отдельно для одного типа - загонял в QHash, а тебе будет достаточно даже QMap (если ключи не использовать). Но тогда у тебя таких списков получится по количеству типов, а вот как один сделать не знаю. Шаблонами если попробовать (сомневаюсь, что получится), но переопределять нужно будет точно.

Answer (score 8):

Можно и даже просто, например сохраняя указатели на виджеты в коллекции `QList` и через мета-магию `Qt` используя метод `setProperty`:

```cpp
void setValue(const QList <QWidget*> &widgets, int value) {
    foreach (QWidget* w, widgets) {
        w->setProperty("value", value);
    }
}

QList <QWidget*> widgets;
widgets.append(new QSpinBox());
widgets.append(new QDoubleSpinBox());
widgets.append(new QSlider());

foreach (QWidget* w, widgets) {
    qDebug() << w->property("value");
}

setValue(widgets, 10);

foreach (QWidget* w, widgets) {
    qDebug() << w->property("value");
}
```

Получаем:

```
QVariant(int, 0)
QVariant(double, 0)
QVariant(int, 0)
QVariant(int, 10)
QVariant(double, 10)
QVariant(int, 10)
```